# Code after while loop not printing in forked process of my C code

Tags: c, exec, fork

C noob here. Code should print "C1: executing ls command" as well as output from executing the `ls -la` command. But Im not seeing either. The output from the other print statements in and before the loop are working fine though.

## C Code

```
    pid_t child1_pid = print_if_err(fork(), "fork");
    if (child1_pid == 0) {
        printf("\nChild Process 1\n");
        printf("Process ID: %d\n", getpid());
        printf("Parent Process ID: %d\n", getppid());

        sleep(2);
        int whale = 6;
        char new_whale[50];
        sprintf(new_whale, "%d", whale);
        setenv("WHALE", new_whale, 1);
        printf("C1: %d\n", whale);

        while(whale > 3) {
            sleep(3);
            whale = whale - 3;
            sprintf(new_whale, "%d", whale);
            setenv("WHALE", new_whale, 1);
            printf("C1: %d\n", whale);
        }

        print_if_err(chdir("/"), "chdir");
        printf("C1: executing ls command");
        execl("ls", "-l", "-a", NULL);

        _exit(0);
    }
```

Comment: Perhaps something in `print_if_err` is the culprit.

Comment: Agree with @R Sahu regarding `print_if_err`.  Can you show that code?

Comment: execl will _fail_: correct is: `execl("/bin/ls", "ls", "-l", "-a", NULL);`. Because you call `_exit(0)` then, the process terminates _without_ flushing its output buffers. Use `exit(0);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible that stdout and stderr are not being flushed before execl is executed. Try fflush(stdout) and fflush(stderr) before execl.

The reason for this behaviour is that printing is slow and printf() actually prints to a buffer which is later flushed all together.